# iPhone App Icon in Binary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, app-store, appstore-approval

I understand many different sized icons for my app are required for App Store Submission according to  [Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW2). However, I am unsure on how to include them? Do I just add them as Icon.png to the Binary?

Comment: After some serious digging, I found an official response from Apple with exact file names and sizing information.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You include them in your project and reference them from your info.plist file under the icon files section.

Here is an updated list of the filenames and sizes you can add:  http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=840/

Answer (score 2):

This is much easier to handle in xcode4 if you have it, just click on your project (should be at the top of the project navigator window) then go to the summary tab, and you can select the icons from there.  Then when you build your app, they will be included in the binary